# Let $X$ be the set of all polynomials of degree $4$ in a single variable $t$ such that every coefficient is a single-digit non-negative integer.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ be the set of all polynomials of degree $4$ in a single variable $t$ such that every coefficient is a single-digit non-negative integer. Find the cardinality of $X$.

Let $p(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ be any polynomial of degree $4$. We see that $a=1,...,9$ and cannot be equal to zero, otherwise we won't have a polynomial of degree $4$. Then $b, c, d, e$ can be any of $0,1,...,9$. So there are $9*10^4$ polynomials of degree $4$. How does this look?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Fine - Btw, here's an out-of -the-box argument: $p(10)$ is an integer in the range $10000,\ldots, 99999$, of which there are $9\cdot 10^4$. Then again, showing rigorously that $p\ne q$ implies $p(10)\ne q(10)$ for $p,q\in X$ is at least as hard as just counting right away as you did.